# ggplot + smooth line with varying thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line chart with width of the line dependent on a variable value. That's pretty straightforward; what throws a wrench in this is that I want the line smoothed. Any suggestions how to feed a changing size variable to "stat_smooth"?

Data:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(ggplot2);library(splines)

data <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date('2014-05-01'), length = 31, by = '1 day'),
    orders = sample(50:100, 31, replace=TRUE),
    revenue = sample(1500:3000, 31, replace=TRUE))
```

If I just use the standard ggplot line chart to plot orders over time, it's easy enough to have the thickness vary by "revenue":

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=orders))
plot + geom_line(aes(size=revenue))
```

[image]
But I want to smooth the lines. The approach I've been using utilizes "stat_smooth" (if there's a better approach, please let me know). The problem is that this doesn't allow for a varying line thickness argument.

Here's how the smooth-line chart looks:

```
plot + stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~ns(x,15), se=FALSE)
```

[image]

If I try to add in a variable for size *dependent on revenue*, it doesn't have any effect:

```
plot + stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~ns(x,15), se=FALSE, aes(size=data$revenue))
```

Is it possible to have a smoothed line thickness change dependent on a variable value?

Comment: Off the top of my head: fit the model outside of ggplot, pull the fitted values into a regular `geom_line` layer.

Comment: @joran, can you add a bit more detail around how you would do that?

Comment: `stat_smooth` is just fitting a `lm` with the formula you provided. Do that separately, and use `predict` to store the predicted values in a separate data frame, and then pass that data frame to `geom_line` layer.

Comment: gotcha. Unfortunately the line isn't as smooth as I'd like it to be: mod1 <- lm(orders~ns(date, 15), data=data);
preds <- predict(mod1);
plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=preds));
plot2 + geom_line()

Comment: ...so call predict at a finer scale, with `x` values you supply at a finer scale.

Comment: Could you provide an example? If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying to predict against a vector n times the length of what I currently have for x. But then won't ggplot not be able to process that, since x and y are of different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly but seems to work. The basic idea is the same as suggested above: using `predict()` a finer resolution.

```
#fit model
mod1<-lm(orders~ns(date,15), data=data)

#predict 500 values
N<-500
newdata <- data.frame(
    date=c(data$date, seq(min(data$date), max(data$date), length.out=N)),
    revenue = c(data$revenue, rep(NA, N))
)
newdata$pred <- predict(mod1, newdata)
newdata <- newdata[order(newdata$date),]
#carry revenue values forward
newdata$revenue <- zoo::na.locf.default(newdata$revenue)
change<-c(TRUE,diff(newdata$revenue)!=0)
newdata$grp<-cumsum(change)
#add rows to help join the segments
newdata<-rbind(newdata, cbind(pred=newdata[which(change)[-1],c("pred")], newdata[which(change)-1,c("date","revenue","grp")]))
```

Then plot with

```
ggplot(newdata, aes(x=date, y=pred, group=grp, size=revenue)) + geom_line()
```

to get

[image]